# i want to create a table with fixed column,but each column show a data from data base, Jsp

Tags: html-table

I want fixed column e.g. 3 , but each column show a data from data base,
for example i have 10 data(row) in my database like `data1`, `data2`, etc.
now I want to show the data like below.

I am using `Jsp` and `HTML`.

```
<tr><td>data 1</td><td>data 2</td><td>data 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>data 4</td><td>data 5</td><td>data 6</td></tr>
<tr><td>data 7</td><td>data 8</td><td>data 9</td></tr>
<tr><td>data 10</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

please specify your problem, if you problem is regarding table arrangement use colspan